# ServicePointManager SetTcpKeepAlive

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have a web site which calls Azure Storage thousands of times a second. All of the storage endpoints are HTTPS. Does anyone know if setting ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive = true will help with performance? It is disabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if enabling tcp keep-alive will help your performance issue (it should be easy enough for you to benchmark), but... if you're calling storage endpoints from your Azure-hosted web site, and storage is in the same region (same data center), you shouldn't need https, since traffic never leaves the data center.

**EDIT** since you're working with the `ServicePointManager`, also consider setting `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm=false`. Otherwise, small tcp packets get buffered up to 1/2-second. If your storage communication is for small (less than ~1400 byte) payloads, this setting should help (especially when dealing with things like Azure Queues, which tend to have very small messages).

Comment: Setting this property doesn't really seem to change much :(